# Увеличение размера счетчика

Tags: css, счетчики

Вот есть код:

```css
.day,
.month {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form class="dateInput">
  <input type="number" class="day">
  <input type="number" class="month">
</form>
```

Когда счетчик достигает 100 или больше, то начиная с третьего числа ничего не видно.
Как можно записать в CSS, так что бы `width` тоже увеличивался ?

**UPD**: Желательно без костылей.

Comment: Без костылей никак. Если интересует вариант на js/jquery, могу предложить свое небольшое решение решение.

Comment: Можете Ваше решению на обозрение показать? Интересно, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: @Cheg Давайте, я не против js/jquery

Comment: @AlisherYerkimbekov а вы весь CSS предоставили? В вашем примере у меня в хроме скрывается не только 3я цифра, но и 2я тоже

Comment: @Cheg Да весь. У меня вторая цифра скрыта на 30%, но её более менее видно чем 3ю

Comment: @AlisherYerkimbekov есть решение, которое корректно отображается лишь в chrome, opera и safari. в firefox, ie и edge невозможно позиционировать стрелки (это нужно чтобы они не перекрывали собой value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var st;


input.addEventListener('input', function() {

  st = this.value + "";

  if (st.length == 1) {
    this.style.width = '30px';
  } else if(st.length == 2) {
    this.style.width = '40px';
  }else{
  this.style.width = '50px'
  }
})
```

```css
.day {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition:width .5s;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="day">
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего - задать width: 50px; - и этого будет вполне достаточно, если количество цифр ограничено 3.

Comment: Скажем, мне нужно ещё что бы тоже самое было и с текстом.